# Full image in Background in a vBox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I was wrote the following code to set the background image in one vBox.

```
vBox.setStyle("backgroundImage", "PreviewBackground.png");
vBox.setStyle("backgroundAttachment", "fixed");
```

Where the height and width of vBox was 250 x 350 and the height and width of background image was 400 x 400. The problem is that the background image doesn't show the full image. The image has cropped. How can i show the full image as a background image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vBox.setStyle("backgroundSize", "100%");
```

Checkout the [backgroundSize](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#styleSummary) style of `Container` class